# plot many categorical variables on single graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, visualization

**Data**

8no independent variables - all catagorical. 3no dependent variables, all calculated from other data for each of the catagories - mean, SD and COV (coefficient of variation).

```
ACCOM_EHCS    : catagorical independent variable with 8 catagories
CV            : continuous dependent variable co-efficient of variation
SD            : continuous dependent variable SD
mean          : continuous dependent variable mean
BUILDING_AGE  : catagorical independent variable with 8 catagories
DBL_GLAZ      : catagorical independent variable with 5 catagories
GOR           : catagorical independent variable with 9 catagories
HhdSize       : catagorical independent variable with 5 catagories
Inc_Group_7s  : catagorical independent variable with 9 catagories
Person_Over_64: catagorical independent variable with 2 catagories
Person_Under_5: catagorical independent variable with 2 catagories
```

**My DF (str)**

```
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 48 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ ACCOM_EHCS    : num  4 2 1 3 7 5 8 NA NA NA ...
 $ CV            : num  {---hidden - sensitive data---} ...
 $ SD            : num  {---hidden - sensitive data---} ...
 $ mean          : num  {---hidden - sensitive data---} ...
 $ BUILDING_AGE  : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 6 4 2 ...
 $ DBL_GLAZ      : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ GOR           : Factor w/ 9 levels "A","B","D","E",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ HhdSize       : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Inc_Group_7s  : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Person_Over_64: int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Person_Under_5: int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

**Problem**

Originally I created 8no individual DFs where i calculated the mean, SD and COV for each variable and the categories within each variable. Then i combined them using:

```
summary <- rbind(ACCOM_EHCS, BUILDING_AGE, DBL_GLAZ, GOR, HhdSize, Inc_Group_7s, Person_Over_64, Person_Under_5)
```

I now have the summary DF, as above and dont know how to progress..

**Question**

How can I (what is the best) visually illustrate the differences in COV for all of the categories?

I would like Y-axis to be COV and the X-axis to be each category (maybe as a bar), so I can visualize the COV for all categories.

Note: the data I am working with is sensitive, so I cannot share.

Comment: Is COV the same as CV?

Comment: Yes, sorry if that wasn't clear